# authenticate.authenticate is not working in desktop app in custom tab integration

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

During integration of OAUTH2, authenticate.authenticate popup is not loaded with login page from  google/hubspot/zoho etc. in Desktop App.

We have attempted with Task Module also, results are same.
With authenticate.authenticate() we could able to access in Teams Web app, but not in desktop app.

In both cases, domain specific URL is not mentioned in valid domains in  manifest file.

Note: if we include domain specific URLs in valid domains in manifest file then it is rejected by Validation team as it is not meeting security constraints.

Tried with both Task Module and authenticate.authenticate popup.
[task module desktop app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8JTi.jpg)

[desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTASX.png)

Comment: Can you share minimal code snippet and check for any errors(refer :DevTools for Microsoft Teams tabs)? where it is happening Static tab or config tab?
Referece-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools